# Database programming joins

Tags: mysql, sql

Sorry, I don't know how to format this so it looks readable.

This is my assignment : Find the book code and book title for each book whose price is greater than the price of at least one book that has the type HOR.

This is what I've come up with so far for the first question:

```
select b.book_code, b.title, b.price from book b
    inner join book b1 on b.price > b1.price
    where b.type = 'HOR';
```

My table looks like this:

> Blockquote

```
mysql> describe book;
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field          | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| BOOK_CODE      | char(4)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| TITLE          | char(40)     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| PUBLISHER_CODE | char(3)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| TYPE           | char(3)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| PRICE          | decimal(4,2) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| PAPERBACK      | char(1)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
6 rows in set (0.09 sec)
```

> Blockquote

Thanks for your help.

Here's what my query returned:

```
 mysql> select b.book_code, b.title, b.price from book b
        ->  inner join book b1 on b.price > b1.price
        ->  where b.type = 'HOR';
    +-----------+-----------------------+-------+
    | book_code | title                 | price |
    +-----------+-----------------------+-------+
    | 0189      | Magic Terror          |  7.99 |
    | 1351      | Dreamcatcher: A Novel | 19.60 |
    | 9611      | Black House           | 18.81 |
    | 1351      | Dreamcatcher: A Novel | 19.60 |
    | 9611      | Black House           | 18.81 |
    | 1351      | Dreamcatcher: A Novel | 19.60 |
    | 9611      | Black House           | 18.81 |
    | 0189      | Magic Terror          |  7.99 |
    | 1351      | Dreamcatcher: A Novel | 19.60 |
    | 9611      | Black House           | 18.81 |
    | 1351      | Dreamcatcher: A Novel | 19.60 |
    | 9611      | Black House           | 18.81 |
    | 1351      | Dreamcatcher: A Novel | 19.60 |
    | 9611      | Black House           | 18.81 |
    | 0189      | Magic Terror          |  7.99 |
    | 1351      | Dreamcatcher: A Novel | 19.60 |
    | 9611      | Black House           | 18.81 |
    | 1351      | Dreamcatcher: A Novel | 19.60 |
    | 9611      | Black House           | 18.81 |
    | 1351      | Dreamcatcher: A Novel | 19.60 |
    | 9611      | Black House           | 18.81 |
    | 0189      | Magic Terror          |  7.99 |
    | 1351      | Dreamcatcher: A Novel | 19.60 |
    | 9611      | Black House           | 18.81 |
    | 1351      | Dreamcatcher: A Novel | 19.60 |
    | 9611      | Black House           | 18.81 |
    | 0189      | Magic Terror          |  7.99 |
    | 1351      | Dreamcatcher: A Novel | 19.60 |
    | 9611      | Black House           | 18.81 |
    | 1351      | Dreamcatcher: A Novel | 19.60 |
    | 9611      | Black House           | 18.81 |
    | 1351      | Dreamcatcher: A Novel | 19.60 |
    | 9611      | Black House           | 18.81 |
    | 1351      | Dreamcatcher: A Novel | 19.60 |
    | 9611      | Black House           | 18.81 |
    | 0189      | Magic Terror          |  7.99 |
    | 1351      | Dreamcatcher: A Novel | 19.60 |
    | 9611      | Black House           | 18.81 |
    | 1351      | Dreamcatcher: A Novel | 19.60 |
    | 9611      | Black House           | 18.81 |
    | 1351      | Dreamcatcher: A Novel | 19.60 |
    | 9611      | Black House           | 18.81 |
    | 1351      | Dreamcatcher: A Novel | 19.60 |
    | 9611      | Black House           | 18.81 |
    | 1351      | Dreamcatcher: A Novel | 19.60 |
    | 9611      | Black House           | 18.81 |
    | 0189      | Magic Terror          |  7.99 |
    | 1351      | Dreamcatcher: A Novel | 19.60 |
    | 9611      | Black House           | 18.81 |
    | 1351      | Dreamcatcher: A Novel | 19.60 |
    | 1351      | Dreamcatcher: A Novel | 19.60 |
    | 9611      | Black House           | 18.81 |
    | 1351      | Dreamcatcher: A Novel | 19.60 |
    | 9611      | Black House           | 18.81 |
    | 0189      | Magic Terror          |  7.99 |
    | 1351      | Dreamcatcher: A Novel | 19.60 |
    | 9611      | Black House           | 18.81 |
    | 0189      | Magic Terror          |  7.99 |
    | 1351      | Dreamcatcher: A Novel | 19.60 |
    | 9611      | Black House           | 18.81 |
    | 1351      | Dreamcatcher: A Novel | 19.60 |
    | 9611      | Black House           | 18.81 |
    +-----------+-----------------------+-------+
    62 rows in set (0.00 sec)

    mysql>
```

Comment: What database engine are you using?

Comment: Also, you could show us what you've got so far using sqlfiddle :) http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: I am using MySQL.  If you want I can post the results of what I got from the select query.

Comment: Do you **have** to use `JOIN` here?

Comment: Your problem here is you are performing an `INNER JOIN` on *every* book of type 'HOR' with a lower price than the book you are selecting's price.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "trick" is using a subquery in the where clause like so:

```
select b.book_code, b.title, b.price 
from book b
where b.price > (select min(price) from book where type = 'HOR');
```

Comment: Thank you.  And to all others who answered.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT `BOOK_CODE`, `TITLE` 
FROM 
`Books` 
WHERE `PRICE` > 
(
    SELECT 
    MIN(`PRICE`) 
    FROM 
    `Books` 
    WHERE 
    `TYPE` = 'HOR'; 
) AS sq
```

This should select the book code and title `WHERE` the price is greater than the lowest price for a book with the type of HOR.

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like this.

```
select b.book_code, b.title, b.price 
from book b
where b.price > (select min(book.prince) from book where book.type = 'HOR')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use nested query.

```
Select book_code, title, price from book
where price > (select min(price) from book where type = "HOR");
```

Answer (score 0):

Answers with sub-queries:

```
select b.book_code, b.title, b.price from book b
WHERE b.price > (SELECT MIN(price) FROM book WHERE type = 'HOR');
```

```
select b.book_code, b.title, b.price from book b
WHERE b.price > ANY(SELECT price FROM book WHERE type = 'HOR');
```

```
select b.book_code, b.title, b.price from book b
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 from book b1 WHERE b1.type = 'HOR' AND b.price > b1.price);
```